# generate equals() in eclipse for a whole package

Tags: java, eclipse

Generating `equals()` automatically in Eclipse is wonderful feature. However, it's still painful to generate it for a whole package. Is there anyway to generate it to a whole package?

Comment: You could probably write an eclipse plugin that does the job.

Comment: umm... why would you want to do that? I mean, there might be cases where you want a different semantic from the one eclipse generates

Comment: @Tedil Sure, you might - but if you know you won't, or at least don't right now, it would be a useful thing to be able to do quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is any ways to apply `Generate hashCode and equals` to whole package.
But there is a better way to open each of files and apply `Generate hashCode and equals`.

Using [lombok](http://projectlombok.org), you can add `equals()` and `hashCode()` by simply adding `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation for a class.

`Generate hashCode and equals` in Eclipse is good feature, however, you have to maintain(regenerate) the generated code when you modify the class, especially when you added or removed the fields of class.

If you use lombok and `@EqualsAndHashCode`, you don't have to regenerate the auto-generated methods. When you modified the class (add or remove fields) and save it (which means Eclipse compiles the modified files), lombok automatically regenerate the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.

Comment: This is a sweet piece of library. But does it work with Eclipse or I do import it in my project?

Comment: download lombok.jar file from the website and execute it. Normally it will detect the eclipse directory and update Eclipse. And then you can add the lombok.jar to the project class path. That's it.